# Compile cvblob library in 32bit on 64bit OS

Tags: ubuntu, 32bit-64bit, cvblobslib

Is there any way for me to compile the cvblob library in 32bit on a 64bit Debian OS? I tried to look for this in the cvblob documentation but couldnt find anything relevant.

Comment: In the general sense, you're looking for [cross-compiling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler). Without knowing details of your build system, hard to make specific recomendations

Comment: I have a 64bit Ubuntu OS 6.10 (Squeeze) and trying to compile libraries in 32bit for a 32bit executable.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`?